# HSQL database: loading a particular Java classpath

Tags: java, hsqldb

I have an in-memory HSQL database (v 1.8) up and running - I am able to connect to it using Java and run "**CREATE TABLE**" queries.

I am trying to create & run stored procedures and from the HSQL docs the way to do it is create an alias and have it point to a Java class. Then have the Java class do the necessary processing the stored procedure would do.

I have created an alias in HSQL using something like the following statement -

```
CREATE ALIAS MySPROC FOR "com.mypackage.MyClass.myFunction";
```

Then I try to run this SPROC using a Java code like the following -

```
java.sql.CallableStatement stmt = cnt.prepareCall(storedProcedureCall);
```

Where cnt is of type java.sql.Connection.

I am getting an error as follows -

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Function not found com.mypackage.MyClass java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mypackage.MyClass in statement [  CALL MySPROC(?,?,?)  ]
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.throwError(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcCallableStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.prepareCall(Unknown Source)
etc.
```

What I understand is that I have to show HSQL the location of "**com.mypackage.MyClass**".

How do I do that?

Comment: Not an answer but just an observation: if you upgrade HSQL to at least 2.2 you can use native SQL procedures in stead of having to do this with Java classes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is create procedure sql statement I have been using in 2.2.9:

```
drop procedure ms.cleanupLocations;
create procedure ms.cleanupLocations(myLocation int)
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN ATOMIC
    delete from ms.mytable where myLocation = 0;
END;
```

Here is Java code to call it:

```
static void cleanupSigSumm(Connection cn, int locationNumber) throws SQLException {
    CallableStatement proc = cn.prepareCall("{ call ms.cleanupSigSumm(?) }");
    proc.setInt(1, locationNumber);
    proc.execute();
}
```